# Adding more Angular standalone components to the default Stackblitz App component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, stackblitz

I created a second standalone `AppNavComponent` component [on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5ibanp?file=src%2Fapp-nav.component.ts).

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'app-nav',
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet],
  template: `<router-outlet>`,
})
export class AppNavComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
}
```

It's imported it the `main` one like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, AppNavComponent],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{name}}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.io/start">
      Learn more about Angular 
    </a>
  `,
})
```

And it produces the error:

```
Cannot find module 'app-nav.component' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line:

```
import { AppNavComponent } from 'app-nav.component';
```

to this line:

```
import { AppNavComponent } from './app-nav.component';
```

Comment: Oh ... Cool ... OK ... That's how I usually do, but the tooling suggested the other way so I thought maybe it had "evolved" ... Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Change the import of `AppNavComponent` in **main.ts** to indicate that the component is located in the same directory as the current file.

**From**

`import { AppNavComponent } from 'app-nav.component';`

**to**

`import { AppNavComponent } from './app-nav.component';`

**[Forked Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ht5zal?file=src%2Fmain.ts)**